# What options do I have for testing an Angular 2 application with Team City?

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, angular, protractor

Over the next two years we will be building a large Angular 2 application.  Part of the test suite will be User Interface Tests.  The Unit Tests and Integration tests will be written in C# with NUnit or MSTest.  The client has chosen Selenium for the User Interface Tests.  Is it possible to write tests for Selenium in C# that can test the Angular 2 User Interface or will Protractor need to be used?  I would like to have all the tests run during a Team City build.   Can Protractor be run in Team City?  If so what does the setup of Protractor look like in Team City?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever you like, but Protractor is preferred way since it has builtin Angular 2 support.

There are couple of useful reporting plugins (they provide TeamCity compatible output i.e. you will see failing test names and total number of tests): `karma-teamcity-reporter` for pure Jasmine tests and `TeamCityReporter` from `jasmine-reporters` for Protractor tests.

Both Protractor and Jasmine tests can be run in TeamCity.

Comment: We are going to end up using Protractor.NET with Selenium and C# to do the Angular Testing.  I found out that Selenium out of the box cannot find the DOM created dynamically by Angular.